# grep error only when creating variable out of results

Tags: bash, grep

I'm parsing some json in bash.  If I do this at a bash command prompt:

> cat junk|grep -Po '"loc":.*?[^\\]",'

It returns:

> "loc": "21.0393,105.7666",

But, if i do this to set a variable with the results:

> test=`cat junk|grep -Po '"loc":.*?[^\\]",'`

It returns:

> grep: missing terminating ] for character class

For some reason the variable encapsulation using {'} seems to trigger something with grep and my regex

junk is file with a bit of json from a query to http://ipinfo.io:

> { "ip": "103.147.184.52", "city": "Cầu Diễn", "region": "Hanoi", "country": "VN", "loc": "21.0393,105.7666", "org": "AS135905 VIETNAM POSTS AND TELECOMMUNICATIONS GROUP", "timezone": "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh", "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth" }

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, when I pasted it, I didn't realize that it trimmed the string... There is an extra escape \ in the grep regex.   I corrected it to show grep -Po '"loc":.*?[^\\\]",'`     I can't use available json parsers on the OS build since they're not allowed/available.  I'm trying to parse out a couple of values from the json without getting heavy-handed with sed or awk.

Comment: TBH I don't really understand your regex, however what you are observing is discussed here [Can someone explain the strange behavior of backslash in command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408507/can-someone-explain-the-strange-behavior-of-backslash-in-command-substitution). Try replacing the backticks (which are a deprecated form of command substitution) by `$(...)`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'll swap that in and try it.   The regex was borrowed from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out by steeldriver that the use of backticks for command substitution has been deprecated.

When I use this form:

> test=$(cat junk|grep -Po '"loc":.*?[^\\]",')

It works as intended.